# scope and lifetime of a pointer to struct which is local to a function

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, linked-list, structure

In the following code I am inserting at last node. It is working fine.
But my doubt is since I have declared Node * last;   locally, so whenever a new call is made a new pointer variable will be created and previous one will be removed from the memory after function gets terminated. So  how come Node * last; is holding addresses from previous call,since every time it will be freshly created?

**first; is pointer to first Node of linked list,it is declared globally.**

```
void insertLast(int x)
{
    Node *last;
    Node *q=new Node;
    q->data=x;
    q->next=NULL;
    if(first==NULL)
        first=last=q;
    else
    {
        last->next=q;
        last=q;
    }
}
 
insertLast(2);
insertLast(5);
insertLast(7);
display(first);
 
output:
2 5 7
```

Comment: Please include a [mcve] of your code in the question

Comment: The `last->next=q;` line is undefined behaviour because, at that point, `last` is uninitialized.

Comment: *So how come Node * last; is holding addresses from previous call* -  Undefined Behaviour. It's quite possible that it only works because you do the calls consecutively and the values are kept in registers/stack is not cleared. It will likely crash if you add one more `insertLast` call after `display`.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I have updated the post.Plz check again.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen I tried to add after displaying.Still it is wroking fine.

Comment: When `first==NULL` is false `last->next=q` is Undefined Behaviour as `last` was never initialised.  All you can do with UB is to fix it.  Trying to reason about UB is pointless by definition.

Comment: you didn't read the link I provided you. Describing code in text is futile when we already know that your code is wrong. You cannot know what parts are relevant and what parts are not and we also know that your code isnt doing what you think it does, hence we require you to post a complete example that reproduces the issue. Anyhow, the error is rather obvious and I tried to write an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simpler example, same effect:

```
#include <iostream>

void DONT_DO_THIS(bool init){
    int x;
    if (init) x = 42;
    else std::cout << x << "\n";
}

void foo() {
    int y = 0;
}

int main() {
    DONT_DO_THIS(true);
    DONT_DO_THIS(false);
    DONT_DO_THIS(false);
    foo();
    DONT_DO_THIS(false);
}
```

Before you read further, try to find out what is the output of this code.

Did you make up your mind?

Do you know what is the output?

Whatever you expect this code to print, it is wrong. The code has undefined behavior and could produce any output. With gcc 11.1 this is the output I get:

```
42
42
0
```

Reading from the local variable `x` when it is not initialized is undefined behavior. You must not do that! If you do anyhow, one possibility is that next time you call the function the `42` is still stored in a register and `x` happens to appear to have that value. In fact `x` has no value in that case. It is said to have an indetermiante value that you cannot read.

When turning on optimizations (`-O3`) this is the output:

```
0
0
0
```

Most likely the compiler realized that the code has UB and optimized away all non-sense code.

No matter what output you get, any output would be in accordance with the C++ standard, because the standard does not mandate what should be the result of compiling code with undefined behavior.

TL;DR: Always initialize variables. Never read from an uninitialized variable. Code with undefined behavior can appear to work, but nevertheless it must be fixed.