# Returning local variable from C++ function?

Tags: c++, return-value, local-variables

There are many ways to return local variables from a function in C++, but why do some work and others don't? Like, I have provided two cases:

**Case 1:**

```
int* fun1()
{
    int x = 20;
    int* ptr = &x;
    return ptr;
}

int main()
{
    int* arr = fun1();
    cout << *arr;
    return 0;
}
```

**Case 2:**

```
int* fun2()
{
    int arr[100];
 
    arr[0] = 10;
    arr[1] = 20;
 
    return arr;
}
 
int main()
{
    int* ptr = fun2();
    cout << ptr[0] << " " << ptr[1];
    return 0;
}
```

Here both `ptr` variable from `fun1()` {case-1} and `arr[]` from `fun2()` {case-2} are local variables to their respective functions. So, why in case-1 does `main()` print the returned value from `fun1()` fine, **but** in case-2 when printing the return value it gives a segmentation fault?

Moreover, what can be a better alternative in both cases?

Comment: Both cases are UBs.

Comment: they are both undefined. Undefined behavior can appear to work. I answered similar question recently: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68098309/scope-and-lifetime-of-a-pointer-to-struct-which-is-local-to-a-function/68098538#68098538 The bottom line is: Undefined beahvior is undefined, no matter if it may appear to "work"

Comment: *"Moreover what can be better alternative in both cases"* return by value, int and `std::pair<int, int>`/`std::array<int, 2>`.

Comment: returning a reference or pointer to a function local variable is always wrong.